# Paypal Sandbox 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I integrated PayPal into our checkout hub a few days a go, using basic client side integration (JavaScript only). Everything was working fine until yesterday afternoon when I started getting status code 500 errors from the following two POSTS (presumably these take place in checkout.js)

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/checkout/EC-[REMOVED]/session/create

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/batch/setbuyer

[REMOVED] was an alphanumerical string. I'm not 100% sure what is and isn't sensitive data in these URL's so I've redacted it just in case.

When my paypal button is clicked, the overlay opens up for Express Checkout, and it begins the 'Logging you in securely' process. But then the login seemingly fails and displays this screen:

[image]

When I press the Login button, the window just closes.

**What I believe:**
I think this has something to do with PayPal's OneTouch. If I clear my logged in accounts it allows me to input the credentials manually. The payment then works but it goes through a legacy looking version of the paypal site instead of the small modern window I am expecting. 
After that, it then attempts to log me in by itself and the aforementioned errors occur.

I understand that 500 codes are usually an issue on their end, but Paypal have assured me that there is no current issue with their sandbox environment and they have suggested I open a technical support ticket. 
I have done this but the last time I opened a support ticket with PayPal they took 6 weeks (literally, not an exaggeration) to reply. So I was hoping maybe someone on here would be able to help a little sooner.

Any alternate suggestions as to why I might be receiving these errors would be greatly apperciated.

For reference, I am seeing these errors in the console in Google Chrome, and my JavaScript code is below:

```
paypal.Button.render({
env: 'sandbox',
client: {
    sandbox: '[REMOVED]',
    production: '[REMOVED]',
},
payment: function() {
    var env = this.props.env;
    var client = this.props.client;
    return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
        transactions: [{
            amount: {
                total: '1',
                currency: 'GBP'
            }
        }]
    });
},
commit: true,
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute();
},
},'#paypal-button');
```

Comment: I am also getting this but when I'm using the older cURL NVP express checkout flow.  500 Internal errors on the same 2 URLs. DoExpressCheckoutPayment method returns an error code of 10001. Upon receiving that I redirect back to paypal to try again, this time presented with the old legacy checkout page which when loading contains unhandledApiError in the query string. The docs on error 10001 are pretty vague. https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&expand=true&locale=en_US&id=FAQ1041